# Curling eyelashes on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hair

Is curling eyelashes on *shabbos assur* because it makes a crease in the eyelashes?

Comment: Or perhaps because one is likely to pull some out, an issue of shearing.

Comment: So just to clarify...it's halachicly forbidden to use one?

Comment: I was just suggesting. I have no idea. I'm a guy. This is absolutely not Halacha l'maaseh for me.

Comment: I'm sure Rabbi Ribiat has this in his Sefer